# Selenium Java example (is Selenium IDE required)?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Is it necessary to download Selenium IDE to execute Selenium examples?

I am trying to execute a Selenium application on Java. Please, help me with the steps and a sample example...

Comment: a simple google search can give you your desired results.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not necessary.

**Selenium IDE** is a tool (a Firefox addon) for recording testcases without writing any code. It works internally with Selenium RC and can export it's code to some languages.

If you want to write Java code, use **Selenium RC** or **Selenium 2 (WebDriver)** with any Java IDE you like.

As Selenium 2 is recommended nowadays, you should use that. [This page from WebDriver docs is full of examples.](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium docs says you can use any IDE the only requirement is  selenium.jar should be in your class path.  i think you should go with Eclipse IDE. Follow the link for Configuration .
[Configuring Selenium  With Eclipse](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_client.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write selenium code manually you don't need to download selenium IDE. But if you want to get java code directly, you need to download it. In this you can record a testcase and you can export that in java.  So it is your choice..

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is Addons of Firefox. It is used only for recording your tests so that time is saved. Recorded code can be exported to your desired language (Java, PHP, Python etc.)